# Lie algebra cohomlogy of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: lie-algebras, homology-cohomology

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a real Lie algebra. How can we prove that $\mathcal{H}^2 (\mathbb{R}^2)\cong \mathbb{R}$, the second cohomology space of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I really appreciate if someone could help me about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology#Chevalley%E2%80%93Eilenberg_complex) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology#Cohomology_in_small_dimensions) paragraph don't do for you? It would also help if you specified coefficient module of your cohomology.

Comment: @Ennar Thank you for the links. By $\mathcal{H}^2 (\mathbb{R}^2)$ I mean $\mathcal{H}^2 (\mathbb{R}^2;\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: If $\mathbf{g}$ is a $n$-dimensional Lie algebra over an arbitrary field: if $\mathbf{g}$ is unimodular (i.e. $\mathrm{Tr}(\mathrm{ad}(\mathfrak{g}))=0$) then $H^n(\mathfrak{g})$ is 1-dimensional, and otherwise $H^n(\mathfrak{g})$ is zero.

Answer (score 2):

For an abelian Lie algebra $L$ over a field $K$, the second cohomology space $H^2(L,K)$, by definition of the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex, is just given by ${\rm Hom} (\Lambda^2 (L),K)$ which has dimension $\binom{d}{2}$, where $d=\dim(L)$.

Comment: Dear @DietrichBurde , thank you so much for the answer. Could you please give me a reference for it? I could show that $H^2 (\mathbb{R}^2;\mathbb{R})=\Lambda^2 (\mathbb{R}^2)$. How can I show that this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Use the dimension formula for the exterior algebra and recall that two finite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic if their dimensions coincide. And note, that $V^*={\rm Hom} (V,K)$ is the dual vector space and has the same dimension as $V$.

Comment: Could you please give a reference for it? I don't know how $H^2 (L,K)$ is given by $Hom(\Lambda^2 (L),K)$ and I want to understand it. I don't know the dimension formula for the exterior algebra.

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology) for the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex for Lie algebra cohomology. By definition, $H^n(L,K)={\rm Hom}(\Lambda^n(L),K)$. So there is nothing to understand further. It is a definition.